# How to get number of requests sent and actually received by server in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, api-testing, stress-testing

I'm using Jmeter in remote env.(1manager server, 3-5 querying servers, 1 target server).
I have fixed EPS/QPS and threads(gradually increasing up to a certain value). I want to know if there is any parameter/plug-in that I can use to get the total number of requests sent to target server and the total number of requests (actually)received by the target server.

PS: If anyone has any other such comments/situations related to this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service)-based system it should be possible to get such information via [JMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions). I believe that all Java MQ implementations should expose some form of statistics via JMX (i.e. [JMSServerMBean](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs_mhome/weblogic/management/configuration/JMSServerMBean.html) for WebLogic) or so you will be able to use [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to explore the metrics.

Once you figure out the required endpoints you can make the collection unattended using [JMXMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/). The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]